# recursive menu causing fatal error: Allowed memory size exhausted

Tags: php, recursion, tree, infinite-loop, recursive-query

I'm not sure what's happening here, I tested this code on localhost but now that I’ve tried going live I’m getting this error message:

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 261900 bytes) in .../functions/tree.php on line 24

I am guessing the code is causing some sort of infinite recursion but I’m a bit perplexed since it worked fine on localhost. I’ve spent a few days trying to get this to function the way I’d like and I’m reluctant to go changing things without some direction. Any ideas on what might be causing this error and/or how to fix it?

```
<?php
function hasChild($parent_id)
{
  $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM categories WHERE parent = '" . $parent_id . "'";
  $qry = mysql_query($sql);
  $rs = mysql_fetch_array($qry);
  return $rs['count'];
}

function CategoryTree($list,$parent,$append)
{

  $list = '<li>'.'<a href="inventory.php?cid=' . $parent['id'] . '&cname=' . $parent['cname'] . '">' . $parent['cname'] . '</a>'.'</li>';


  if (hasChild($parent['id'])) // check if the id has a child
  {
    $append++;
    $list .= "<ul class='child child".$append."'>";
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM categories WHERE parent = '" . $parent['id'] . "'";
    $qry = mysql_query($sql);
    $child = mysql_fetch_array($qry);
    do{
      $list .= CategoryTree($list,$child,$append); //this is line 24
    }while($child = mysql_fetch_array($qry));
    $list .= "</ul>";
  }
  return $list;
}
function CategoryList()
{
  $list = "";

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM categories WHERE (parent = 0 OR parent IS NULL)";
  $qry = mysql_query($sql);
  $parent = mysql_fetch_array($qry);
  $mainlist = "<ul class='parent'>";
  do{
    $mainlist .= CategoryTree($list,$parent,$append = 0);
  }while($parent = mysql_fetch_array($qry));
  $list .= "</ul>";
  return $mainlist;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Localhost settings could be different from your PHP server.
If your PHP server doesn’t have enough memory then PHP will stop with That error.

You need to increase the Maximum Allowed memory size, You can fix this by adding this the following at the top of your script:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '128M');
```

Or If you don't want to touch the code then you can set this in your `php.ini` setting file.

Comment: I am still receiving an error message, but the allowed size is larger and error line is now on line 21 for some reason…
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 44 bytes) in /functions/tree.php on line 21

Comment: Ok then set it to `-1` watch out for memory leaks

Answer (score 0):

You are gathering up a large amount of string data. I would consider refactoring my code to output the contents of $list and $mainlist more frequently. I try to set my code up to output once per iteration through a loop.

Also, when outputting HTML tags, I generally output every logical tag line, ie as it would appear if in an actual HTML document. This also adds to the readability of my output if I ever have to view source to figure out what output looks like.